# GE refrigerator will not get cold

Tags: appliances

My refrigerator got unplugged for about 5 hours.  I plugged it  back in.  It is running and freezer is getting colder but the refrigerator is staying at 65 degrees.  It has b

Comment: Stop opening the door :)

Comment: I have a feeling you have only written half of a question - just going off of the half written sentence at the end.

Comment: Was the refrigerator tilted on a dolly? If the freezer is working then the compressor must be OK. Did the temperature setting for the refrigerator inadvertently get changed?

Comment: That's a vey good question, was the fridge physically move during the 5 hour period? Was it tilted, or did it go for a ride in a vehicle?

Comment: It was unplugged for 5 hours, but how long has it since been plugged in and running? It will not cool down instantly and will be even slower if you keep opening the door...

Answer (score 1):

Typically when the freezer works fine but the fridge part doesn't get cold it's because the fan that blows the cold air from the freezer into the fridge isn't working.

If you are comfortable taking apart and reassembling the covering inside at the back of the freezer:

- Unplug the refrigerator and look at the fan.
- Is it jammed?  Does it turn freely?
- If it looks okay, plug the refrigerator in.
- Does the fan run?
- If so, are the vents leading to the fridge part blocked?

Replacing a broken fan is easy enough, but, as with most replacement parts, it can be expensive.

For illustrations, see the manuals for your specific model on the manufacturer's web site.

There are also many YouTube videos showing how to replace the fan (e.g. [Whirlpool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7zEunxy70Y)).